# Hamachi login failed on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, networking, vpn

I am trying to use [Hamachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogMeIn_Hamachi) on Debian (Wheezy 7.8) with an ARM architecture.
Whenever I try to login, it fails:

```
# hamachi login
Logging in ..... failed
```

I tried this command on another Ubuntu machine and it's working fine.

I downloaded the latest Hamachi version from [this page](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux)
and installed  `logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.139-1_armhf.deb`.

Comment: you may want to provide more log/error details...and `Hamachi` for `linux` is in beta so there will be bugs

Comment: @gwillie Do you know where I can find the logs file? On the command line I don't see any other errors except the one I wrote: *login failed*.

Comment: @justsomeguy When you edit posts, please look for (and fix) obvious problems, like linking to the French version of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Today I connected to the Hamachi network on RaspberryPi 3 with system Ubuntu Server 18.04.04 LTS. 
I needed the steps described below to join the network:

1. Start server:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start
   ```
2. Then set up nickname:

   ```
   sudo hamachi set-nick raspberry
   ```
3. Then login successfully:

   ```
   sudo hamachi login
   ```
4. After that I connected to the account:

   ```
   sudo hamachi attach 'account@fake.mail'
   ```
5. And connected to network:

   ```
   sudo hamachi join adresSieci
   ```

It worked for me today; hopefully it will help you.